# MPMoviePlayerController plays .mp4 file on all devices except arm64 (iPhone 5S, Retina iPad Mini etc)

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, mp4

I have an app that uses MPMoviePlayerController to play an mp4 video file embedded in a view (not fullscreen). It's been working fine until the arm64 devices came out, on which it doesn't play but remains black.

Has anyone else came across this issue and if so, do you have a fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, changing the video from an advanced profile to baseline fixed it, but I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Sounds as if your encoding does... Option1: ...not properly adhere to apple's standards and hence you were lucky it played at least on one platform. Option2: ... properly adhere to apple's standards but they got a bug in their 64bit implementation of the codec. I would suggest you to build a minimal example (including content snippet) and file a technical incident with that stuff bundled. If it boils down to option2, your incident will be recouped.

Comment: Thanks @Till I'll try filing a technical incident and see how that goes.